# Update nested attributes objects independently from parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, single-table-inheritance, sti

I have a parent model `'page'` and **nested attributes** model `'page_modules'` which at same time are modeled by *'Single Table Inheritance'* pattern.

My problem is when I try to save different generated `'page_modules'`, if one of these is not validated, the whole model and nested attributes are not updated, even if some of these nested attributes pass the validation. ¿Is there a way to update all the validated `'page_modules'` and only refuse not validated `'page_modules'`?

Comment: If you try to add record for all of parent and nested records and something is not valid everything will be rollbacked or will not commit. So suitable option here is to sore them one by one in iteration.
And still having fast query execution you can use transaction method of active record.

Comment: UI wise a better alternative is probally to use AJAX to do atomical update/create queries for each nested record. Nested attributes is really a kludge to create/update multiple resources in one form submission in classical apps.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly you want to silently drop the nested attributes if they are invalid and continue anyways. You can do this with the [`reject_if:` option](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :page_modules
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :page_modules, reject_if: :page_module_invalid?

  private
  
  def page_module_invalid?(attributes)
    !page_modules.new(attributes).valid?
  end   
end
```

Comment: It doesn't works. If I try to save two different page_modules, if one is invalid and the other is valid, when I submit, the update is triggered in PageController and if there is an error validation, it doesn't updates the whole process, and throws error. I think that the `page_modules` update should work independently from `page` with an iteration, but I don't know how to manage params to do so.

Comment: As explained previously in my comment - use ajax instead to submit the items one by one. While you can cobble something together where you loop through them it's going be a much better user experience and easier to handle then all the edge cases that can occur if you're creating tht items outside of a transaction.

Comment: I am considering two options. Using Ajax as you are suggesting, or implementing jquery validations, displaying errors in the view and disabling submit button if `page_module`data is not valid. I appreciate your help.Thanks @max @hiren-bhalani.